# How to Open a page in Parent frame while clicking on Button.... for example button to perform login event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, window, new-operator, frame

I have used two frame in my web page... the below frame contain the validation of user for login information like username and password....

There is a button named "Login" which is attached with onClick event....

When I press Login button... the validation are done through Javascript and the new
  page also opened,,,  but in the same frame in which the login button is placed...

so , the my problem is how to open a page in Parent frmae when i click on "Login" Button... i know this can be done through the hyperlink...but i want to apply on Button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, or parent.*frame_name*.location.href

`<a href="#" onclick="parent.frames[i].location.href='whateverpageyoulike.html'">`